# Are Groovy pipes real UNIX pipes?

Tags: groovy

I just started today looking into Groovy. I consider using it to replace some of my more complex bash scripts.

One of its very interesting concepts for me is the possibility to [use pipes easily](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management):

```
proc1 = 'ls'.execute()
proc2 = 'tr -d o'.execute()
proc3 = 'tr -d e'.execute()
proc4 = 'tr -d i'.execute()
proc1 | proc2 | proc3 | proc4
proc4.waitFor()
```

That's amazing. But my question is: Does this use real UNIX pipes (when run e.g. on Linux), or is this just a simulation with Java streams? (And if so, is it much slower/more inefficient?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to operator overloading, it eventually calls into [ProcessGroovyMethods.pipeTo()](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.java) in the Groovy runtime, which does indeed simulate pipes using java streams:

```
    /**
     * Allows one Process to asynchronously pipe data to another Process.
     *
     * @param left  a Process instance
     * @param right a Process to pipe output to
     * @return the second Process to allow chaining
     * @throws java.io.IOException if an IOException occurs.
     * @since 1.5.2
     */
    public static Process pipeTo(final Process left, final Process right) throws IOException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(getIn(left));
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(getOut(right));
                byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                int next;
                try {
                    while ((next = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, next);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new GroovyRuntimeException("exception while reading process stream", e);
                } finally {
                    closeWithWarning(out);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return right;
    }
```

I can't speak to the amount of overhead involved off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 5):

I found groovy pipes simulation much slower than unix pipes:

Bash command

```
zcat dump.sql.gz | mysql -u${mysql_user} --password=${mysql_password} -D${db_name}
```

Takes about 40 min

Same thing with groovy

```
def proc1 = ["zcat", "${sqlGzFile.getPath()}"].execute()
def proc2 = ["mysql", "-u${mysqlUser}", "--password=${mysqlPassword}", "-D$dbName"].execute()   
proc1 | proc2
proc2.waitFor()
```

takes about 2 hours and 40 minutes

But you can do pipes with:

```
def proc = ["sh", "-c",  "zcat dump.sql.gz | mysql -u${mysql_user} --password=${mysql_password} -D${db_name}"].execute()
proc.waitFor()
```

Answer (score 2):

Groovy cannot use Unix pipes, because Unix pipes must be setup *before* the child processes are started. But your example first starts all process and connects them with pipes *later*.

Also Groovy would have to call some filehandle manipulation system calls (`dup`, `dup2`) which are not available in the JVM without using some additional native library.

Comment: I am sure dup, dup2 are available in the JVM. The JVM already does a whole bunch of native file handle wrangling. They may not be exposed to the user if that is what you mean.